# Cloudsearch geo query filter/limit by distance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudsearch

I am using cloud search with lambda, I face a problem with geo query (i m using haversin ).

I need to get nearby data (marketers) based on user's current longitude/latitude, compared with marketer longitude /latitude stored in db.

I am able to get all the data sorted by distance, but not able to limit/filter by distance, kindly suggest how to achieve this with cloudsearch.

```
var params = {
    query: "matchall",
    expr:"{\"distance\":\"haversin(13.185474,77.524030,latlon.latitude,latlon.longitude)\"},{\"expr.distance\":{,5}}",        
    queryParser:"structured",
    sort:"distance asc",
    return:"id,distance,latlon,_score"};
```

In the above query I am getting distance in return and also data sorted by distance, now want to limit it for only 5 or 10 kms.

Please suggest any alternate way if it is not possible with cloudsearch (any other way then haversin). I need to get nearby data with limited kms.

Answer (score 1):

With CloudSearch you can apply a filter query to get all data within a bounding box ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-locations.html#within-area)). CloudSearch does not  have the option to get locations within a circle. But when you have all data within a bounding box of (for example) 5 km, sorted by distance, it is easy to remove the data > 5km from the CloudSearch result set with a Lambda function. So, the solution for you is to add a filter query to your params, and do a simple post processing on the result of the CloudSearch query.

Now suppose you want all data within distance *dist* from point *lat*,*lng*

First calculate the bounding box coordinates. I use the [geopoint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geopoint) library for this calculation.

```
  var GEO = require('geopoint');
  var point = new GEO(lat, lng);
  var points = point.boundingCoordinates(Number(dist), -1, true); //[(SW), (NE)]
  var SW = points[0];
  var NE = points[1];

  // GeoPoint expresses the boundingbox via SW, NE. CloudSearch uses NW, SE
  var NWlat = NE.latitude();
  var NWlng = SW.longitude();
  var SElat = SW.latitude();
  var SElng = NE.longitude();
```

Next step is to add a filterquery to your params:

```
var params = {
    ...
    “filterQuery” = latlon:['" + NWlat + "," + NWlng + "','" + SElat + "," + SElng + "'],
    ...
}
```

Now the CloudSearch query will give you all points within a bounding box, ordered by distance. The only thing left to do is to remove the "data > distance" from the result set

Comment: Thanks @Peter. But not seems this is efficient solution, also apply pagination is problematic with this case. I have apply bound box filter query by taking topleft and bottomright data, but it gives you some extra data as haversin computes based on circle and bound box query apply filter by square.